# Python Рекурсия

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть задача:
Кузнечик прыгает по столбикам, расположенным на одной линии на равных расстояниях друг от друга. Столбики имеют порядковые номера от 1 до n
слева направо. В начале Кузнечик сидит на столбике с номером 1. Он может прыгнуть на следующий столбик или сразу на второй столбик, считая от текущего.

Найдите количество способов, которыми Кузнечик может добраться до столбика с номером n. Учитывайте, что Кузнечик не может прыгать назад.

Внимание! Данная задача должна решаться рекурсией. Вы не можете использовать циклы

Тесты:

```
входные данные
3
выходные данные
2

входные данные
4
выходные данные
3

входные данные
45
выходные данные
1134903170
```

Как это решить рекурсией а не циклами???

Comment: Какой максимальный N во входных? Но вообще, скорее всего, требуется использование "ленивого" ДП: вы пишете самое глупое решение через рекурсию: f(n) = f(n - 1) + f(n - 2), f(1) = 1, f(2) = 1. И добавляете внешний массив dp[MAXN+1], в который записываете ответы для каждого рассчитанного на данный момент n. То есть вам нужно будет добавить в начало рекурсивной функции условие `if dp[n] != -1: return dp[n]`, а перед возвращением значения для каждого n написать `dp[n] = res; return res`. Без использования дополнительной памяти, можно просто переписать цикл в рекурсию, но это уже извращение.

Comment: Входные данные содержат одно натуральное число n (2≤n≤45).

Comment: можете написать кодом?

Comment: https://www.python-course.eu/python3_memoization.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cкорее всего, требуется использование "ленивого" ДП: вы пишете самое глупое решение через рекурсию: f(n) = f(n - 1) + f(n - 2), f(1) = 1, f(2) = 1 и добавляете внешний массив dp[MAXN+1], в который записываете ответы для каждого рассчитанного на данный момент n.

Без использования дополнительной памяти, можно просто переписать цикл в рекурсию, но это уже извращение.

```
def f(n):
    global dp
    if dp[n] != -1:
        return dp[n]
    dp[n] = f(n - 1) + f(n - 2)
    return dp[n]

dp = [-1] * 46
dp[0], dp[1] = 0, 1
```